# запуск selenium без dos окна python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Привет.У меня при работе запускается dos окно chromedriver'a.Возможен ли запуск chrome без появления окна?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
chromeDriverPath = r'C:\drivers\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath,chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://google.com")

driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(0, 0)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Я попробовал,но не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

У селениум есть так называемый безголовый режим (без отображения окна), вам нужно добавить в свой код следующее:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
```

Соответственно ваш экземпляр браузера должен включать в себя данные опции и выглядеть примерно так `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`

Так же советовал бы использовать `options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')` дабы умные сайты не замечали автоматизации.

К дополнению если на нужных вам страницах вам не нужны картинки, вы может блокировать их подгузку что бы слегка ускорить общий процесс (но очень незначительно):

```
prefs={"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2 }
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
```